# $\overline{\mathbb{Z_2}}$ closure of $\mathbb{Z_2}$, $\alpha, \beta$ roots of $x^3+x^2+1$, $x^3+x+1$. Show $\mathbb{Z}(\alpha) = \mathbb{Z}(\beta)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field

Let $\overline{\mathbb{Z_2}}$ be an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Z_2}$, and let $\alpha, \beta \in \overline{\mathbb{Z_2}}$ be zeroes of $x^3+x^2+1$ and of $x^3+x+1$, respectively. Show that $\mathbb{Z}(\alpha) = \mathbb{Z}(\beta)$.

The solution:

[image]

Theorem 33.3:

[image]

First of all, shouldn't $\mathbb{Z_2}$ have $2$ elements? Why $\mathbb{Z}(\alpha)$ and $\mathbb{Z}(\beta)$ are extensions of degree $3$?

Comment: When you write ${\rm Z}(\alpha)$, etc., I think you mean ${\bf Z}_2(\alpha)$, etc. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Also, is it not explained somewhere in your materials that if $p$ of degree $n$ is irreducible over $F$ and $p(\alpha)=0$ then $F(\alpha)$ is an extension of $F$ of degree $n$?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $K$ is any field over which $x^3+x^2+1$ is irreducible, then $K(\alpha)\cong K(\beta)$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are zeroes
of $x^3+x^2+1$ and $x^3+x+1$. That is because $1/\alpha$ is a zero
of $x^3+x+1$.